# Do you usually add "the" in front of things like history, culture and society?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Japanese history
>
> the Japanese history
>
> Japanese society
>
> the Japanese society
>
> Japanese culture
>
> the Japanese culture

Which ones do you think are commoner?  Any difference in meaning?

If one is considered better than the other, I'd like to know the reason.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not in examples like yours.

'History' and 'culture' can be *non-countable nouns*, so they don't always need an article:

> I study history.
> I love culture.

When speaking about a *specific* history or culture this way, you should use an article:

> I love the history of Japan.

But in your example, 'Japanese culture' and 'Japanese history' are non-countable, so there is no need for an article, although some may add it. 'Japanese culture' is also specific enough not to need the definite article for specificity.